# Which process will be faster back-end work or sql query?

Tags: mysql, django, database, performance

**The scenario**

I was working on a search system with Django 2 and MySQL. The search system hits the database with parameter and compiles **4 table** join query. This makes the execution for the search slower for a huge number of data.

The query:

```
itemViewCategory = Item.objects.raw("select *, company.slug as companySlug, company.name as companyName, field.id as fieldId, field.name as fieldName, category.name as categoryName from company inner join category on company.business_type = category.id inner join category_field on category_field.category_id = category.id inner join custom_field as field on category_field.field_id = field.id where category.id = (select id from category where slug= %s) and field.name LIKE %s order by company.name", [slug,product])
```

Also, I need to calculate the count of the data that is required for a different operation.

I can do that in **2 different ways**

1. First is to use a for loop to count that data.
2. Or do another query to count that data.

Now my question is which process will be **faster**? I did some research but I could not get a satisfying answer and I am confused right now. Can someone help me with this query?

Comment: In general the database will be much faster at counting the data. You may need to tune your query to get advantage of the indexes (and create indexes if necessary).

Comment: Now if I'm not mistaken you shoul replace this `where category.id = (select id from category where slug= %s) ` with just `where category.slug = %s`. Otherwise your a doing an unnecessary subquery

Comment: Yes, I agree with you cuz MySql queries will be faster and also save a lot of memory and CPU time too. Its general logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database will be able to optimize the count better if all you need is counting the query result and you don't need the result set. Under this circumstance, if you do the counting in python the database will have to serialise the result set, and python will have to deserialise it, which are a lot of unnecessary traffic and computation cycles.

However, if you actually need the result set as well, then doing two queries (one to fetch the result and one to count) is very likely going to be slower than just doing one query and to do the counting on python, especially if the query is slow/complex and the database can't do an index count as the database may actually have to run through the data twice. Additionally, depending on your transaction isolation level, doing two queries may actually give you different count in the two queries if you are at transaction isolation level that allows phantom reads, as there may be rows that have been added/removed between the two queries.

Ultimately though, you should benchmark your operations if you're concerned about this.